# How to properly reinstall NVIDIA driver on fedora 32 after issue with update

Tags: fedora, nvidia

I had some OS updates on fedora 32. I installed them, but now I have [the issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/hr7u1z/black_screen_on_booting_after_update/) described here. Basically, the OS was updated, but not the NVIDIA driver to the updated OS. So, I lost the graphical interface. I need to reinstall the NVIDIA driver. My question is: do I need to first uninstall the current NVIDIA driver? or can I just install directly the NVIDIA driver like I did before without uninstalling anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: do I need to first uninstall the current NVIDIA driver?

Yes.

> or can I just install directly the NVIDIA driver like I did before without uninstalling anything?

The driver provided by NVIDIA is **not** meant to be used by end-users. You should use the RPMfusion package instead:

https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA

Comment: do you know if there's a way to check if I reinstall the NVIDIA drivers correctly? I have a graphical interface now, but I can't run nvidia-smi, which the command I used to check. I can run nvidia-setting though.

Comment: Edit: I installed xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda. Now everything is working. Thanks!